# How to synchronize buttons on two differents pages?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, button

How to have the same button pushed on two differents pages?
I have on my pages A and B the sames buttons "On" and "Off"(they do the same thing on the two pages). And when I press "On" the "On" button is disabled, If I press "Off" the off button is disabled and the "On" button is enabled.

I'm looking for a synchronization for my buttons between pages A and B. 
For example: When I press "On" on page A I want the "On" button already enabled on page B.

The sames buttons on pages A and B:

```
<button id="onButton" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button" ng-model="peer.enable" ng-click="vm.enable()"  onclick="this.disabled=true">on</button>
<button id="offButton" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button" ng-model="peer.disable" ng-click="vm.disable()" onclick="this.disabled=true">off</button>
```

It seems to be easy but I don't know where to begin,

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you use angular you should add the corresponding tag, some more competent person may come

Comment: And also add the angular version, please

Comment: Are both of these pages being displayed simultaneously in different browsers or are you asking for the display to be consistent after navigation?  The distinction is important and will mean a very different level of effort.

Comment: I'm using angularJS.

Comment: Thanks @jonatjano for the tips

Comment: I'm asking for the display to be consistent during all my navigation, only on my browser. Thanks i'll update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service to share data between controllers in AngularJS. This works because in AngularJS services are singletons - once you have created an instance of the service it is shared everywhere it is accessed. Here is a very simple example demonstrating this. Checking a box in the area of the view corresponding to one controller will update it in the area of the view corresponding to the other controller.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .service('sharedDataService', function() {
    var service = {
      checkboxData: {
        checkbox1: false,
        checkbox2: false
      }
    }
    
    return service;
  })
  .controller('ctrl_1', ($scope, sharedDataService) => {
    $scope.checkboxData = sharedDataService.checkboxData;
  })
  .controller('ctrl_2', ($scope, sharedDataService) => {
    $scope.checkboxData = sharedDataService.checkboxData;
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl_1">
    <h3>Controller 1</h3>
    <div>
      <label>Checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxData.checkbox1" />
  </label>
      <br/>
      <label>Checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxData.checkbox2" />
  </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ctrl_2">
    <h3>Controller 2</h3>
    <div>
      <label>Checkbox 1
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxData.checkbox1" />
  </label>
      <br/>
      <label>Checkbox 2
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxData.checkbox2" />
  </label></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control a page which is not loaded to the DOM yet, unless it is processed by the server and you change it in the server side - but leave that for now.

To be consistent with your navigation, [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/append) the current status of the buttons in the URL before you navigate out of the page by a [query string parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), [parse them](https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript) when page is loaded and based on the values set your buttons status.

for example, add these parameters (or any other format you think appropriate)

`&onButton=0&offButton=1`

You can also use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) in order to keep the status of the buttons.

As you can see, you have numerous options to save the buttons status. the logic is:

- save the status before navigating out
- get the status after navigating in
- set the buttons per the parsed status

Comment: Thank you Alon, I tried with this way to and it also works. And i want to thank you too for this very methodological answer !

Comment: @MathBob you're welcome, I'm happy my answer was helpful to you, even if it's not the accepted one - if you learned something from it and gained knowledge, I did my work :). Please do consider voting up (+1) for my answer so it will be cataloged as helpful for future users as well, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm less than 15 reputation, my votes are recorded but it didn't change the policy.